# Android -- Support 1.6+, and Support for Deprecated Code in 1.5?

Tags: android, api, deprecated

I'm trying to build a app that uses the SmsMessage class but there are two versions depending on the API level of the device:

android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage (deprecated for 1.6 and above)

android.telephony.SmsMessage (the new class for 1.6 and up)

I want to target 1.5 and yet have the newer class (android.telephony.SmsMessage) run on devices with 1.6 or higher. How do I do this?

I have already tired this: http://devtcg.blogspot.com/2009/12/gracefully-supporting-multiple-android.html but I couldn't get it to work (the author doesn't mention how he/she handles the different imports, the exact api level settings etc.)

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Date;
import com.apps.myapp.Utilities;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;//*NOTE* depreciated in v1.6+

public class OfflineSMSReceiver extends SMSReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("SMS_RECEIVED");

        System.out.println(Utilities.getNow());
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        Date date; 
        long timeStamp;
        String time;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                timeStamp = msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
                date = new Date(timeStamp);
                time = this.getTime(date.getHours(),date.getMinutes(),date.getSeconds());
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                str += "TIME: "+time+"\t"+this.getNowDate();
            }

            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to target `android-4` or higher, otherwise the newer class will not exist.

With respect to loading in the correct version, you can use conditional class loading, demonstrated in [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) for the two editions of the contacts content provider. Also, [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) is what Google has to say on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your first link was very helpful. After looking at that code, I think I understand what I have to do. The key is setting up the abstract class correctly. I'll report back after trying this on my own. Thanks again.

Comment: Your example worked perfectly. Just to make sure, because I set the min SDK to 3 (target to 4), the app should appear in the market for devices that run 1.5+? Thanks again.

Comment: @borg17of20: Whether or not you show up in the Market will be determined by your `android:minSdkVersion` setting in your manifest (see `uses-sdk` element), not by your build target when running the build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Using CommonsWare's example, I was able to create this (which works):

[manifest settings]

1.Set the target SDK to 4 (or higher) (Android 1.6+)

2.Set the min SDK to 3 (Android 1.5)

[OfflineSMSReceiver.java]

```
import java.util.Date;
import com.apps.myapp.Utilities;
import com.apps.myapp.SmsMessageBridge;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OfflineSMSReceiver extends SMSReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("SMS_RECEIVED");

        System.out.println(Utilities.getNow());
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessageBridge[] msgs = null;

        Date date; 
        long timeStamp;
        String time;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessageBridge[pdus.length];           
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessageBridge.INSTANCE.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                timeStamp = msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
                date = new Date(timeStamp);
                time = this.getTime(date.getHours(),date.getMinutes(),date.getSeconds());
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                str += "TIME: "+time+"\t"+this.getNowDate();
            }

            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

[SmsMessageBridge.java]

```
import android.os.Build;

public abstract class SmsMessageBridge
{
    public abstract SmsMessageBridge createFromPdu(byte[] pdu);
    public abstract long getTimestampMillis();
    public abstract String getOriginatingAddress();
    public abstract String getMessageBody();

    public static final SmsMessageBridge INSTANCE = getBridge();

    private static SmsMessageBridge getBridge()
    {
        final int sdkVersion = new Integer(Build.VERSION.SDK).intValue();

        if(sdkVersion>3)
        {
            return new NewSmsMessage();
        }
        else
        {
            return new OldSmsMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

[OldSmsMessage.java]

```
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;//*NOTE* depreciated in v1.6+

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class OldSmsMessage extends SmsMessageBridge
{
    private SmsMessage myMSG;

    @Override
    public SmsMessageBridge createFromPdu(byte[] pdu)
    {
        myMSG = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimestampMillis()
    {
        return myMSG.getTimestampMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public String getOriginatingAddress()
    {
        return myMSG.getOriginatingAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessageBody()
    {
        System.out.println("v1.5");
        return myMSG.getMessageBody();
    }
}
```

[NewSmsMessage.java]

```
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class NewSmsMessage extends SmsMessageBridge
{
    private SmsMessage myMSG;

    @Override
    public SmsMessageBridge createFromPdu(byte[] pdu)
    {
        myMSG = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessageBody()
    {
        //System.out.println("v1.6+");
        return myMSG.getMessageBody();
    }

    @Override
    public String getOriginatingAddress()
    {
        return myMSG.getOriginatingAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimestampMillis()
    {
        return myMSG.getTimestampMillis();
    }

}
```

Thanks again to CommonsWare.